# ArcMap TextSymbol in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#

I'm looking to do the following.  Create a point on a map at a given coordinate (x,y) and then display text at that point.  Right now I can create a shape file but nothing is displayed on the map.  Hopefully someone can tell me why

Here is my code:

```
ArcDisplay.IRgbColor color = new RgbColorClass()
{
    Red   = 255,
    Green = 255,
    Blue  = 255
};

IPoint point = new PointClass()
{
    X = 0.0,
    Y = 0.0,
    Z = 0.0,
    SpatialReference = myMap.Map.SpatialReference
};

IElement elem = null;
ITextElement txtElement = new TextElementClass();
element = textElement as IElement;

ITextSymbol textSymbol = new TextSymbolClass();
textSymbol.Color = color;
textSymbol.Size = 16;
textSymbol.Font = (stdole.IFontDisp)OLE.GetIFontDispFromFont(new Font("Arial" , 16 , FontStyle.Bold);

element.Geometry = point as IGeometry;

textSymbol.Text = "My Test Text";
txtElement.Symbol = textSymbol;

((ITextElement)element).Symbol = textSymbol;

IGrpahicsLayer graphicsLayer = new CompositeGraphicsLayerClass();
((ILayer)graphicsLayer).Name = "Text Layer";
IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = graphicsLayer as IGraphicsContainer;
graphicsContainer.AddElement(element , 0);

myMap.AddLayer(graphicsLayer as ILayer);
((ILayer)graphicsLayer).Draw(esriDrawPhase.esriDPGeography , null , null);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I used to do it like this while in non-dynamic-display mode (warning haven't used this code in a while): -- In dynamic display mode it will flicker - so you will need another method for that.

```
IActiveView activeView = mapControl.Map as IActiveView;
ITextElement pTextElement;
IElement pElement;
ICallout pCallout;
IFormattedTextSymbol pTextSymbol;
IGraphicsContainer pGraphicsContainer;

pTextElement = new TextElementClass();
pElement = pTextElement as IElement;
pTextElement.Text = message;

ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = activeView.ScreenDisplay;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IDisplayTransformation displayTransformation = screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation;

int x, y;
displayTransformation.FromMapPoint(anchorPoint, out x, out y);IPoint messagePoint = mapControl.ToMapPoint(x, y - 100); //this is in pixels 
pElement.Geometry = messagePoint;

pTextSymbol = new TextSymbol();
pCallout = new BalloonCallout();
pTextSymbol.Background = pCallout as ITextBackground;
pCallout.AnchorPoint = anchorPoint;
pTextElement.Symbol = pTextSymbol;


if (pGraphicsContainer == null) pGraphicsContainer = activeView as IGraphicsContainer; 
pGraphicsContainer.AddElement(pElement, 0);
pElement.Activate(activeView.ScreenDisplay);
activeView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, pElement, null);
```

Comment: pTextElement.Text = message;

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there - it could be something that you've already checked, but sometimes we overlook the simple stuff (I'm guilty of this constantly). But are the labels turned on for the feature?

Comment: Labels are not turned off.  Thanks though